# Redirection from email addresses bound to site that asks them

Tags: email, browser-addons, spam-prevention, browser-plugin

I would like to:

1. Have distinct email address for any site I register on
2. Quick way to generate and "bind" random address to a site
3. Automatic forwarding from these addreses to "main" address
4. Block any address that I have generated

That approach would allow to have distinct address for each site and makes it harder to hack on my credentials if it gets compromised. Also, it allows to see if a site leaks its email database to spammers, you can easily block leaked address.

I think I could do it using some postfix hackery for my own domain. Generation/binding could be done via browser addon, also possible. But anyway, does any web-based service I described exist? 10minutemail is good, but addresses are transient and there is no address-site mapping available.

Comment: google does that with mainaddress+sometag@gmail.com. you can then just filter the tags.

Comment: Yes, but this is not very random address. Smart spammers would strip +sometag part, wouldn't they?

Comment: trashmail.net - you have to pay if you want more than 10 forwards or a lifespan of more than 1 month, but it's great for creating an email address for those that require activation, and you can always update the email to another trashmail, or to another more permanent email once you trust them